# capacitor camera is not loading images for preview on android

Tags: ionic-framework, camera, base64, photo, capacitor

my code is as follows

```
import { Camera, CameraResultType, CameraSource, Photo } from '@capacitor/camera';
....
const capturedPhoto = await Camera.getPhoto({
            resultType: CameraResultType.Uri,
            source: CameraSource.Camera,
            quality: 100
        });
const base64Data = await this.readAsBase64(capturedPhoto);

        this.photos['image'][this.myindex] = base64Data;
        this.myindex++;
        this.photos.reverse();
```

and I am using this.photos['image'] to loop through and display it. Its working on web browser but not on android device. Any help would be highly appriciated

Comment: To say I am trying to get photos using camera only

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `resultType` to `Base64`.
See [docs](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/camera#photo):

> The base64 encoded string representation of the image, if using CameraResultType.Base64.

You can also use [`convertFileSrc(...)​`](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/core-apis/web#convertfilesrc) for this:

```js
const capturedPhoto = await Camera.getPhoto({
  resultType: CameraResultType.Uri,
  source: CameraSource.Camera,
  quality: 100
});
const fileSrc = Capacitor.convertFileSrc(capturedPhoto.path),
document.getElementById("savedPhoto").src = fileSrc;
```

```html
<img id="savedPhoto" />
```

Btw: If you can share strings, you could also just share the image directly in Base64 format.

Comment: I am converting image to base64encode format after capturing image using 
```const base64Data = await this.readAsBase64(capturedPhoto);```
its workinng on web-browser, but its not disaplying on my ionic-android app. sorry if I miss anything

Comment: Yes and these are two examples how you can solve this problem.